# How to check a variable value within a template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Problem : I want to show different templates based on the user selection.

Question : Is there a way to check which radio button was selected just using markup(Spacebars) and not using click event on the radio button to get the value. 
Following is the example of what I want to do.

```
<template name="category">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="studentGroup" id="studentYes" value="true" type="radio"> Yes
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="studentGroup" id="studentNo" value="false" type="radio"> No
  </label>
</template>
```

Within this conditional block I want to check which radio button was selected so I can show the correct template.

```
{{#if value}}
   {{> studentTemplate}}
{{else}}
   {{> regularTemplate}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this currently is to use a click event to get the value. There might be community packages that automate this for you, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, spacebars doesn't support such feature. AngularJs does this for you for free. You can use Meteor and AngulaJs if you want. Check [this article](https://medium.com/@zfxuan/the-wonderful-duo-using-meteor-and-angularjs-together-4d603a4651bf).